# Manage two .C with same name but from differents submodules

Tags: c, git, makefile, git-submodules

I have an issue on a C project, where I integrate two different git submodules but coincidently they both have a stats.c and stats.h into them.

When I compile the whole project, it compiles until the linker tries to do its job.

It seems clear that we should not have twice files with same filenames. But how to manage this case? Because I can't really modify directly the file in both of the submodules, I mean I can't push commits into thoses repos.

Do you have some idea on how to implement a solution to be able to compile and keep track of both of the submodules?

I already tried the following :

- renaming one of the c files : compilation and linking then works

**Edit**

Here is the linker message

```
[path]/arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: build/stats.o: in function `stat_init':  
[myproject]/Lib/stats.c:57: multiple definition of \`stat_init\'; build/stats.o:[myproject]/Lib/stats.c:57: first defined here
```

From my understanding it's not an issue from the .h but from the two .c that have the same name (here stats.c).
For me the linker tries twice to link the same .o which was either  overwritten or ignored during the compilation of the second .c

Comment: It's possible to link together files with the same file name (if they lie in different locations).
But you can have problems if two different files are compiled to the same object file (thus the last over writing the first). So, could you post the exact message returned by the linker, you could also give building information (makefile for instance)

Comment: "renaming files : compilation then works"
You mean all building process on does it fails on linking phase?

Comment: As @Mathieu implies, this is all entirely dependent on your build system and the way you can solve this.

Comment: @Mathieu  "You mean all building process on does it fails on linking" I mean then the linking works fine

Comment: @Mathieu I'm adding the linker message in the originla post

Comment: @jinTgreater you're right, my issue is coming from the way the makefile is working, I'm looking for a good way to solve that (Other than crating a rule just for this specific case)

Comment: @tho The short paper [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Recursive-Make-Considered-Harmful-Miller/dcb6cbe07ec4a25f506525d2f6dca89b8f7632d7) by Peter Miller has some good points that might help you, in particular his example Makefile setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue : by renaming one of the .C.
For any other user having the same issue, another solution could have been to adapt the makefile to avoid two .o having the same name.

Hope this could help!